# query adding only new data to a table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table of historical data.  I need to run a query that only adds rows for data not in the historical table already.  Both the query and the table have matching unique row ID's.

When my table has data up to 1 week ago, when I run the query I only want to add data that is from the last week.  The table has over a million rows and the query usually returns 20,000 rows for each day.  I never know how many days I need to go back though so I can't make this a set week long query.

I tried using a subquery that showed all of the ID's in the history table and use that to filter the new query by using "Not In(Select.....)" but it takes so long it basically crashes.

I can link the table to the query through the ID's and show only results that are in the historical table, but I can't figure out how to show results that are NOT in the historical table.

Comment: So you already tried a `INSERT INTO yourTable SELECT id from yourOthertable WHERE ID not in (select id from yourTable)` and it froze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two options:

1 - Make the ID field the key field (no duplicates allowed) and use an append query.  Existing rows will cause an error message and not be added; new rows will be appended.

2 - Make an outer join from the new table to the historical table that forces all records from the new table to be in the query, and select on a Null ID from the historical table.  This will give the records from the new table that do not match records on the historical table, which can then be appended to the historical table.

There's also nothing wrong in doing both of these.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I hadn't thought of making the ID field have no duplicates.

I am also using the is null idea you have.  That works perfectly and they also work together as a good double check that everything is working correctly.